# weighted sum of matrices optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I'm beginner in optimization and welcome any guide in this field.

I have 15 matrices (i.e., `Di` of size `(n*m)`) and want to find best weights (i.e., `wi`) for weighted averaging them and make a better matrix that is more similar to one given matrix (i.e., `Dt`).

In fact my objective function is like it:

```
min [norm2(sum(wi * Di) - Dt) + norm2(W)]
for i=1 ... 15    s.t. sum(wi) = 1 , wi >= 0
```

How can I optimize this function in Matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are describing a simple [Quadratic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming), that can be easily optimized using Matlab's [`quadprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html).

Here how it goes:

You objective function is `[norm2(sum(wi * Di) - Dt) + norm2(W)]` subject to some linear constraints on `w`. Let's re-write it using some simplified notations. Let `w` be a 15-by-1 vector of unknowns. Let `D` be an `n*m`-by-15 matrix (each column is one of the `Di` matrices you have - written as a single column), and `Dt` is a `n*m`-by-1 vector (same as your `Dt` but written as a column vector). Now some linear algebra (using the fact that ||x||^2 = x'*x and that argmin x is equivalent to argmin x^2)

```
[norm2(sum(wi * Di) - Dt)^2 + norm2(W)^2] =
(D*w-Dt)'*(D*w-Dt) + w'*w =
w'D'Dw - 2w'D'Dt + Dt'Dt + w'w =
w'(D'D+I)w - 2w'D'Dt + Dt'Dt
```

The last term `Dt'Dt` is constant w.r.t `w` and therefore can be discarded during minimization, leaving you with

```
H = 2*(D'*D+eye(15));
f = -2*Dt'*D;
```

As for the constraint `sum(w)=1`, this can easily be defined by

```
Aeq = ones(1,15);
beq = 1;
```

And a lower bound `lb = zeros(15,1)` will ensure that all `w_i>=0`.

And the quadratic optimization:

```
w = quadprog( H, f, [], [], Aeq, beq, lb );
```

Should do the trick for you!

Comment: @NereaGonzalezVazquez in this particular case quadratic programming is more suited than genetic algorithm.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanantion was very useful for me.

Comment: But I have a problem with H. For calculating term D' * D, I have two 3d matrix (i.e., (m * n * 15) * (n * m * 15)). I did D(:,:,i)' * D(:,:,i) for i:1...15 in a loop, and the result was a m * m * 15 matrix. Is it true? If yes, how can I add it with eye(15)?

Comment: @roya - please read my solution carefully: I convert the `m`-by-`n` matrices to `m*n`-by-1 vectors (simply reshaping them) this will simplify the algebra and allows for simple solution.

Comment: Oh. you are right! I hadn't understood it. Thanks :)

Comment: Finally I finished it but the result isn't meaningful and one of wi is 1 randomly and the others are zeros. In my problem the dimension of each Di is 4500*4500. Do you think it is too big and optimization is failed because of dimensionality?

Comment: @roya (1) the dimensionality of `Di` is meaningless - the effective dimension of your problem is 15. As you can see the coefficients of `quadprog` are of size 15-by-15 and 15-by-1. (2) Try supplying `quadprog` with `x0` - an initial guess `x0=ones(1,15)/15` - does this affect the result? (3) what are the typical values of `H` and `f`? you might have a problem with coefficients that are very large causing numerical instabilities.

Comment: @roya: coming to think about it, you have `L2` regularization term on `w` **and** `L1` constraint (`sum(w_i)=1`) - in this case it is not surprising you get `w` that is binary. Try to remove the `L2` regularization term (the `eye(15)` component of `H`) and see what happens.

Comment: removing L2 regularization term made no difference, but removing L1 constraint let wi select difference values between 0 to 1.5. Now I must do some other works to can evaluate these values are good or not. Thank you for your useful notes. :)

Comment: Sorry for my more question. I used from learned W in my work. But it seems the learned weights aren't suitable. The iteration parameter of quadprog's output is only 4. Is it usual?

Comment: @roya I do not understand your question. why your learned weights are not okay?

Comment: I mean these Wi which are learned from training set didn't work for my test set. I.e., sum(wi * D'i) - D't is bigger than sum(D'i) - D't. where D'i and D't are extracted from test set.

Comment: @roya machine learning can be tricky sometimes... is it possible that the training set and test set are not sampled from the same distribution?

Comment: My dataset is Corel 5K that is the most famous in image annotation and its training and testing set are fixed. But now I tested Wi in training set and it was good for it. Yes, it seems learning weights fails because of my dataset. Thank you anyway :)